# rails interview question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got this question in a previous interview and couldnt do it , any idea?
What does this return? Where would it be used?

```
module ApplicationHelper
 def show_flash
flash.map{|key, value| content_tag(:div, value, {:class => key})}
 end
end
```

Comment: Perhaps look up [Hash#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html), or whatever flash quacks like. Then you'll need to find out/know how show_flash integrates into RoR and perhaps the result of 'content_tag'. Done. (Short answer: It allows customization of the "flash" displayed on the page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'flash' is a ruby-on-rails convention for storing information generated in one request (say, "invalid username" or "session not found" or "thanks for buying from us" or "cart updated") temporarily for being rendered into the next view from the client.

The flash is a hash-like object.

The `.map` method on hash-like objects will iterate over all items in the hash; in this case, the `.map` method is being passed a block that accepts two parameters (which it names `key` and `value`, because the `key` could be used to look up the `value` from the hash). The block uses the `content_tag` helper to output new `<div>` elements with the value from the hash and the CSS selector-class `key`.

So for a flash like this: `{:name => "sars", :food => "pizza"}`

It would emit HTML roughly like this: `<div class="name">sars</div><div class="food">pizza</div>`.

This is a clever little helper method that probably saves a fair bit of typing, but it makes some assumptions: order in the view doesn't matter, all the keys are either in the CSS already or the CSS is prepared to handle unknown class elements in a graceful way. This helper might only be used once in a template, but it'd still be helpful to have as a method that could be dropped into other projects later.

Answer (score 0):

module [ApplicationHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html)
  def show_flash
    [flash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Flash.html).[map](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003128){|key, value| [content_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#M002245)(:div, value, {:class => key})}
  end
end